# What's causing the border on this embedded SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

In Chromium it's not visible - but it is on pretty much everything else - but there is a what looks like a border around the SVG, well, you can see the top and bottom lines (top one is not clear here, but it's there).

[image: The line surrounding the SVG]

This is the HTML that gets generated.

```
<div class="purple-gradient-background header-has-block">
  <div class="container px-md-5 embed-block">[[omitted]]</div>

  <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 86" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="10.5864654%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" id="linearGradient-1">
            <stop stop-color="#F28F53" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#ED555F" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <g id="svg_graphic-standalone-1-V4" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M0,50.0114382 C309.731575,4.65760206 558.064908,4.66285455 745,50.0271956 C931.935092,95.3915367 1163.60176,95.3862842 1440,50.0114382 L1440,86 L0,86 L0,50.0114382 Z" id="BG" fill="#FAF7FB"></path>
        <path d="M1440,50.3528061 C1163.60176,95.6971472 931.935092,95.6871472 745,50.3228061 C558.064908,4.95846499 309.731575,4.96846499 0,50.3528061 L0,50.3528061 L0,34.3528061 C309.601759,-10.7852514 557.935092,-11.2785847 745,32.8728061 C932.064908,77.0241969 1163.73157,77.5175302 1440,34.3528061 Z M1440,-1.52766688e-12 L0,-1.52766688e-12 L0,-1.64719392 L1440,-1.64719392 L1440,-1.52766688e-12 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The enclosing `<div>` goes around other items as well so cannot be causing the line.

I have tried removing the stroke information from the `g` element, and setting the width to zero. It had no effect.

Examination of the CSS assigned to the SVG shows there is no border, margin or padding:

```
box-sizing: border-box
display: inline
float: none
line-height: 24px
position: static
z-index: auto
```

Comment: it most likely is not due to the svg itself but a padding issue. when the underlying element has a dark background it might help to set negative margins or try some paddings to get rid of the line. without a real code example its difficult to figure out

Comment: You can solve it using flexbox. Check out this example. https://jsfiddle.net/bw81nfae/

Comment: Thanks Alex, that does work - BOZ, I appreciate the work you put in there I am just a little wary of throwing something so heavyweight into the mix, we already have a  lot of flex stuff going on. I'll go with the hack :-) this site's going live very soon...

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695988/svgs-in-a-css-grid-with-0px-gap-displays-background-color

Comment: Danny, yes, I'd just figured out it was a rounding issue. Thanks.