# Empty space between SVG paths

Tags: html, css, svg

When I create multiple paths, that have same vertices and I create a SVG file, when I open it with any modern browser there is a white space between the paths. I suggest its result of how the SVG files are calculated, before being drawn. I have tried setting the [stroke properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#StrokeProperties) such stroke-width, stroke-linejoin and make sure the stroke color matches the fill color but, the result is very ugly. Is there a proper way to remove the empty space between the paths, or I should consider adding a background behind the path to hide the empty space?

Here is an image showing the empty space between the paths.

[image]

Here is the code for the SVG path, without any stroke:

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ups a problem!</title>
</head>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="163.545" height="197.679" viewBox="0 0 163.54 197.68" enable-background="new 0 0 163.54 197.68" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#BD796BFF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 110.092,197.679L 0,123.374"/>
    <path fill="#BC7667FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 51.0984,-1.90735e-005L 0,123.374"/>
    <path fill="#BB7A68FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 115.726,42.8555L 51.0984,-1.90735e-005"/>
    <path fill="#B97564FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 115.726,42.8555L 163.545,134.819"/>
    <path fill="#B97464FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 163.545,134.819L 110.092,197.679"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the code for the SVG path, when stroke is applied

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ups a problem!</title>
</head>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="163.545" height="197.679" viewBox="0 0 163.54 197.68" enable-background="new 0 0 163.54 197.68" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#BD796BFF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 110.092,197.679L 0,123.374" stroke="#BD796BFF" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path fill="#BC7667FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 51.0984,-1.90735e-005L 0,123.374" stroke="#BC7667FF" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path fill="#BB7A68FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 115.726,42.8555L 51.0984,-1.90735e-005" stroke="#BB7A68FF" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path fill="#B97564FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 115.726,42.8555L 163.545,134.819" stroke="#B97564FF" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path fill="#B97464FF" d="M 109.547,99.5815L 163.545,134.819L 110.092,197.679" stroke="#B97464FF" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sometimes it happens not only in browsers but also apps like illustrator, I think adding a background with the middle tone color should solve that.

Comment: You can use CSS to help offset the issue `svg path { stroke: red; stroke-width: 6px; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; }` but this is a common issue with SVGs.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695988/svgs-in-a-css-grid-with-0px-gap-displays-background-color