thin lines appear when rendering adjacent squares in SVG
I have thin lines appearing having the background color in this SVG in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox when nine white squares are adjacent.
Is this inherent to SVG or a bug?
If not a bug is there a way to get rid of these thin lines?
this is the source code of the SVG


<svg id="SVGCanvas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #000000" viewBox="-1 -1 5 5" >
    <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="0" y="1"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="0" y="2"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="1" y="0"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="1" y="1"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="1" y="2"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="2" y="0"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="2" y="1"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="2" y="2"  width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
    </g>
</svg>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695988/svgs-in-a-css-grid-with-0px-gap-displays-background-color

The link in the comment of Danny provides the answer


<svg id="SVGCanvas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #000000" viewBox="-1 -1 5 5" >
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
    svg {
        overflow: visible;
    }
    ]]>
    </style>
    
    <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="0" y="1"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="0" y="2"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="1" y="0"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="1" y="1"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="1" y="2"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="2" y="0"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="2" y="1"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="2" y="2"  width="1.01" height="1.01" fill="white"/>
    </g>
</svg>



